# Accesing class method from other process

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

I have a class (`Node`) which spawns some processes and distributes tasks between them, collects results, sends them back. Now I'm trying to measure average time it took for node to process a task (I'm assuming that all task are roughly similar, so by doing it I can understand whether I need to add computing power via Amazon EC2 to finish in time).

Every time the one of processes finished the calculations, it calls the `grab_result` method of `Node` and passes the result (and some info, like time spent calculating) to the method. At `grab_result` method I add the result to the result queue, and I'm also trying to append time to `times`, a list an attribute of `Node`. But when I'm finished with tasks, i check the list and it's empty.

If I replace a list with a queue, it starts working, but it's really inconvenient to use queue in this case - I need to get all the items to a list, calculate the average and add them back to the queue. Appending to a list is an atomic operation (as to my knowledge), so I'm not sure how is it that items are not getting appended.

Here's my code:

```
class Node:

    def __init__(self, function, master_ip, master_port, process_count=None):
        self.is_alive = True
        self.function = function
        self.master_ip = master_ip
        self.master_port = master_port
        self.tasks = multiprocessing.Queue()
        self.results = multiprocessing.Queue()
        self.thread = threading.Thread(target=self.main)
        self.lock = multiprocessing.RLock()
        self.times = []

        if process_count == None:
            self.process_count = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
        else:
            self.process_count = process_count
        self.processes = [_NodeProcess(self) for i in range(self.process_count)]

    def main(self):
        while self.is_alive:
            socket = Objsocket()
            if socket.connect(self.master_ip, self.master_port):
                print('Connected to master at {}:{}'.format(self.master_ip, self.master_port))
            else:
                time.sleep(1)
                continue

            while self.is_alive:
                try:
                    if self.tasks.empty():
                        socket.send({'header': 'task_request'})
                        answer = socket.receive()
                        if answer['header'] == 'task':
                            task = answer['task']
                            self.tasks.put(task)
                            print('Got task "{}"'.format(task))
                        elif answer['header'] == 'no_task':
                            pass

                    if not self.results.empty():
                        socket.send(self.results.get())
                        print('Sent result')

                except ConnectionLostError:
                    break

            print('Disconnected')
            socket.close()

    def start(self):
        self.thread.start()
        for process in self.processes:
            process.start()
        print('Started node with {} processes'.format(len(self.processes)))

    def stop(self):
        for process in self.processes:
            process.terminate()
        self.is_alive = False
        self.thread.join()
        print('Stopped node')

    def give_task(self):
        return self.tasks.get()

    def grab_result(self, result):
        self.results.put(result)
        with self.lock: self.times.append(result['time'])


class _NodeProcess:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.process = multiprocessing.Process(target=self.main)

    def terminate(self):
        self.process.terminate()

    def start(self):
        self.process.start()

    def main(self):
        while True:
            task = self.master.give_task()
            t = time.perf_counter()
            result = {'header': 'result', 'result': self.master.function(task), 'task': task, 'time': time.perf_counter() - t}
            with self.master.lock: self.master.grab_result(result)
```

Comment: "... so I'm not sure how is it that items are not getting appended." The answer is in the title.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, so it's not possible to acces a class method from other process? (BTW, it is run (added prints), it's the list that doesn't change)

Comment: Each process has its own copy of each of the objects. The classes in `multiprocessing` add handling that allow them to communicate between processes. This is why they must be used.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, I see now why the queue works. But what should I use in this case? A pipe, connection, or something else? I'm sorry to ask probably stupid questions. but I don't have much knowledge in multiprocessing, so I'm not sure what to choose.

Comment: Why does the result of the operation need to go back into the queue? Have the main process handle it directly.

Comment: It's another queue for results (called `results`), from which I give results on demand to the main node.

Comment: why not just use threads?

Comment: @phoet because I want to use multiple cores at a time, which is not possible with threads.